# get created item details in webhook url of podio

Tags: webhooks, podio, hipchat

I want to get the item name, item created by, item assigned in webhook url.

like in webhook https://api.domain.com/v1/message?appname={{app_name}}&itemname={{item_name}}&itemassignedto={{item_assigned_to}}

is there anyway like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do in that way. When the webhook is invoked you will only get an item_id as a POST parameter. Use this to make an API request to get the item the webhook was called on and you get the exact same result.